# What are the maximum number of columns in the input data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, max

i must import a big data file in matlab , and its size is abute 300 MB.
now i want to know what are the maximum number of columns ,that i can imort to matlab. so divided that file to some small file.
please hellp me

Comment: This only depends on your hardware (amount of RAM!). There is no real limit otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "maximum" number of columns that you can create for a matrix.  What's the limiting factor is your RAM (à la knedlsepp), the **data type of the matrix** (which is also important... a lot of people overlook this), your operating system, and also what version of MATLAB you're using - specifically whether it's 32 or 64 bit.

If you want a more definitive answer, here's a comprehensive chart from MathWorks forums on what you can allocate given your OS version, MATLAB version and the data type of the matrix you want to create:

[image]

The link to this post is here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711-what-is-the-maximum-matrix-size-for-each-platform

Even though the above chart is for MATLAB R2007a, the sizes will most likely not have changed over the evolution of the software.

There are a few caveats with the above figure that you need to take into account:

- The above table also takes your workspace size into account. As such, if you have other variables in memory and you are trying to allocate a matrix that tries to reach the limit seen in the charge, you will not be successful in its allocation.
- The above table assumes that MATLAB has just been launched with no major processing carried out in a `startup.m` file.
- The above table assumes that there is unlimited system memory, so RAM plus any virtual memory or swap file being available.
- The above table's actual limits will be less if there is insufficient system memory available, usually due to the swap file being too small.

Comment: vary grateful for your answers.

Comment: my win is 8.1  and my matlab version is 2013 and both 64bit. and my system ram is 4GB . but i dont know how many Column i can import to matlab. please help me.